# Reduce the complexity from code

Tags: java, sonarlint

I am using below code and used two continue statement depending on some logic but sonar list showing this issue `Reduce the total number of break and continue statements in this loop to use at most one.`

How to resolve this issue?

```
for (HashMap<String, String> objRequestIdVO : pObjTicketId) {
    List<TicketDetailsDO> objTicketDetailslist = storeManagerDao.getTicketDetailsWithTicketId(objRequestIdVO.get("requestId"));
    if (null == objTicketDetailslist || objTicketDetailslist.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }

    Integer iDesiredDsicount = objTicketDetailslist.get(0).getDesiredDiscount();
    String iSubDept = objTicketDetailslist.get(0).getSubdeptTicket().getSubDeptId();
    List<MCouponDO> objMCounponList = storeManagerDao.getMcouponData(iDesiredDsicount, iSubDept);

    if (null == objMCounponList || objMCounponList.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }

    String strHeader = objMCounponList.get(0).getHeader();
    objHeaderVO = new HeaderVO();
    objHeaderVO.setHeader(strHeader);
    objHeaderVO.setRequestId(objRequestIdVO.get("requestId"));
    objHeaderVOList.add(objHeaderVO);
}
```

Comment: Use apache common utils, `CollectionUtils#isNotEmpty` to reduce complexity in `if` statements

Answer (score 6):

Change the null check continue, to not null check and proceed. The code will be executed only if the not null check passes, which is same as saying continue if null.

```
for (HashMap<String, String> objRequestIdVO : pObjTicketId) {
    List<TicketDetailsDO> objTicketDetailslist = storeManagerDao.getTicketDetailsWithTicketId(objRequestIdVO.get("requestId"));
    if (!(null == objTicketDetailslist || objTicketDetailslist.isEmpty())) {
        Integer iDesiredDsicount = objTicketDetailslist.get(0).getDesiredDiscount();
        String iSubDept = objTicketDetailslist.get(0).getSubdeptTicket().getSubDeptId();
        List<MCouponDO> objMCounponList = storeManagerDao.getMcouponData(iDesiredDsicount, iSubDept);
        if (!(null == objMCounponList || objMCounponList.isEmpty()) {
            String strHeader = objMCounponList.get(0).getHeader();
            objHeaderVO = new HeaderVO();
            objHeaderVO.setHeader(strHeader);
            objHeaderVO.setRequestId(objRequestIdVO.get("requestId"));
            objHeaderVOList.add(objHeaderVO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think use of continue is better.

Comment: both perform the same functionality,  use of continue is discouraged as it reduces the code readability.

Comment: I agree. You should try to get rid of continues where you can. (+1)

Comment: @Jaiprakash Can you please tell me why its showing this error?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty Which error are you talking about, the original complaint from SonarQube or a new error?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty The use of `continue` is often considered bad style and confusing.  Personally I think there was nothing wrong with your original code.  But hey if your analyzer complains about it, what can you do ;p

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.  Bad indentation is ***much*** worse than a couple of `continue` statements with respect to readability.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty The readability of the reworked code could be improved by using proper indentation and perhaps some boolean algebra though. E.g. `if (objTicketDetailslist != null && !objTicketDetailslist.isEmpty())`

Comment: They're nested `if`s, just not indented as such.

Comment: @Arjan seen that ifs are nested, not sequential after complaining :) ([[this](https://gist.github.com/zapl/bb5fff5a3ce6b16f2cb004488772a9b0)] is the code with formatting and the oddness of the conditions fixed)

Comment: Yes, using if/else statements can help reduce the use of `continue` and/or `break` statements.  However, they can also increase code complexity, especially when they are nested.  Nesting adds +1 to the complexity count for each level of nesting, in addition to the counts for the `if` and `else` blocks themselves.  Just something to think about.

Personally, I think it's easier to read the multiple `continue` and `break` statements than having multiple, nested if/else statements.  (+ 2¢)

Answer (score 2):

You could use streams replacing the continues with filters.

```
pObjTicketId.stream()
                .map(m-> m.get("requestId"))
                .map(reqId ->
                        Optional.ofNullable(storeManagerDao.getTicketDetailsWithTicketId(reqId))
                        .filter(l->!l.isEmpty())
                        .map(l->l.get(0))
                        .map(ticketDetails->
                                storeManagerDao.getMcouponData(ticketDetails.getDesiredDiscount(),
                                        ticketDetails.getSubdeptTicket().getSubDeptId())
                        )
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(l->!l.isEmpty())
                        .map(l->l.get(0))
                        .map(couponDo-> {
                            HeaderVO headerVO = new HeaderVO();
                            headerVO.setHeader(couponDo.getHeader());
                            headerVO.setRequestId(oreqId);
                            return headerVO;
                        })
                )
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I am not using jdk1.8

Comment: There's a trade off with using features for the sake of using features and readability - cant see the use of java 8 here to be fair - just my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You have a bigger problem than fixing Sonar warning if calls - `storeManagerDao.getTicketDetailsWithTicketId(objRequestIdVO.get("requestId"))` & `storeManagerDao.getMcouponData(iDesiredDsicount, iSubDept)` are about making DB calls.This is a big performance point and one should  - **Never ever make DB calls from within a loop, this is far more dangerous than multiple continue & break statements**

So I would first restructure your DAO call - `storeManagerDao.getTicketDetailsWithTicketId` to run `IN` sql query for a bunch of `objRequestIdVO.get("requestId")` in one go , outside your main loop & produce a `Map<String,List<TicketDetailsDO>>` ...that will automatically get rid of your first `if` .

Next you repeat same process for constructing a `Map<String,List<MCouponDO> objMCounponList>` by iterating previous map `Map<String,List<TicketDetailsDO>>` where key of this map is something like - `iDesiredDsicount|iSubDept` .

This way you will have two disconnected loops and **only two DB calls** & your Sonar warning gets automatically solved on the way.